# NsMutableArray null value

Tags: nsmutablearray

I have a situation here. I have a UITableviewController with textfields in it in the cell. Each cellthas a textfield in it. The user enters the value in the textfields and i am saving the textfield data in to an NSMutableArray. But if the user doesnot enter a single field then my array gives the error

"CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: *** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 2". NSmutableArray cannot have a null value. How will i handle this situation. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of quick solutions: I'm assuming that you must have a value in the array at the index that corresponds to the row, so what to put in?   Stuff an `[NSNull null]` object in there, or simply an empty string.

```c
if (!txtField.text)  // if the textfield's text is null
{
    [myMutableArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

One issue about this is that when reading your array, you cannot assume that the array holds a string: you must check it for `[NSNull null]` before setting your text.

Another solution to the issue would be to simply create an `NSMutableDictionary` to hold the values you wish to store, the key would be the `NSIndexPath` and the value would be the value you are storing.  If the value is `null`, don't store anything at all.  This way you would have no need to store null values.

Comment: Thank u so much for the quick reply.